# Getting Listed as an "Off Topic" Option for Stack Overflow?

Tags: feature-request

How can we get the Magento Stack Exchange beta site listed as an on topic source for non programming Magento questions asked on StackOverflow?

That is, when a question is being closed on StackOverflow for being off topic, you're presented with the following dialog.

[image]

How can we have `magento.stackexchange.com` listed as an option here? (fore questions tagged `magento`)

Comment: I'm afraid this is not possible for site which are in beta sate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How should we handle Magento questions on Stackoverflow?](http://meta.magento.stackexchange.com/questions/36/how-should-we-handle-magento-questions-on-stackoverflow)